# How to check whether my PC supports PCI Express

Tags: linux, pci-express

I'm trying to figure out whether my system supports PCI Express without opening up the box. lspci doesn't mention "Express" or "PCI-e" anywhere, but dmesg reports that a "PCI Express Hot Plug Controller Driver" is in use.

Comment: Why are you avoiding opening the PC? Due to a warranty sticker? Could you lookup your PC from the manufacturer/supplier to see what is on the product specification?

Comment: This would be a fun solution to see +1. I wouldn't mind having this ability for when I am not in front of a machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easiest thing you can do is restart the machine and write down the model number then Google it and look up the specification.

Simple, but works!

Comment: That's a good point, the BIOS POST screen will usually display a model number of some kind which as you say can be fed into Google.  Nice idea.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the motherboard make and model so you can google it, but you don't want to reboot, you should be able to get that info from /sys/class/dmi/id/board_vendor and /sys/class/dmi/id/board_name

Answer (score -2):

One thing to note is if your machine has a 1x, 2x, 4x, 8x, 16x PCI-E port and then buy the appropriate hardware.

Comment: -1, Irrelevant.